# How to change const std::shared_ptr after first assignment?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

If I define a `shared_ptr` and a `const shared_ptr` of the same type, like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> first = std::shared_ptr<int>(new int);
const std::shared_ptr<int> second = std::shared_ptr<int>();
```

And later try to change the value of the `const shared_ptr` like this:

```
second = first;
```

It cause a compile error (as it should). But even if I try to cast away the const part:

```
(std::shared_ptr<int>)second = first;
```

The result of the code above is that `second` ends up being Empty, while `first` is untouched (eg ref count is still 1).

How can I change the value of a `const shared_ptr` after it was originally set? Is this even possible with std's pointer?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you actually want `std::shared_ptr<const int>`?

Comment: Why? If you want to modify `second`, don't mark it `const`. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Justin no, I was even considering adding a "PS I don't want shared_ptr<const int>" to the original question as I knew someone would ask :)  Thanks though!

Comment: Trying to modify a `const std::shared_ptr<type>` is the same as trying to modify a `type * const`.  You can't do it.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Its a public member of a class and can be accessed from outside, but I don't want anyone changing it. However, there is a special condition where the class need to recreate it internally. I know I could write a getter function, but I'm trying to keep the class usage short and with less clutter.

Comment: If you need to modify it, it shouldn't be const. That said, the right cast is `const_cast<std::shared_ptr<int>&>(second)`. But lying to the compiler is never a good idea.

Comment: @RonenNess Just write a getter. The extra `()` is trivial.

Comment: @PeteBecker Wouldn't modifying `second` as part of the cast result in `undefined behavior` since it was in fact declared `const`?

Comment: @Pete Becker this seems to work, thanks! You should put it as an answer so I can accept / upvote

Comment: @Justin That's my last resort if I'll find no other way. Its a member that needs to be accessed a lot though, so I'd hate it. :/

Comment: Note that @PeteBecker's solution is undefined behaviour since the object was declared `const` in the beginning. Depending on how you are actually using it, you might be able to use [`std::launder`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder) to make it not undefined.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast -- "Modifying a const object through a non-const access path and referring to a volatile object through a non-volatile glvalue results in undefined behavior."

Comment: @RonenNess "That's my last resort". Don't. Seriously, don't do this. It's unclear code. The extra parens really don't hurt anything. Just use them. It improves readability

Comment: Just make a public `const &` to the private variable you want to give access to.  It requires you to defined your special member functions though.

Comment: @NathanOliver that would be a waste of one perfectly good machine word per object.

Comment: @n.m. True.  Personally I would just make a getter than returns a `const &` but if the OP doesn't ant to call a function it might be the best alternative.

Comment: Look at `std::shared_ptr` itself. It has an internally modifiable raw pointer, and a `get()` function to expose a read-only view of it. That's how stuff is expected to work in a C++ library. If you don't like it, perhaps consider switching to a different language.

Comment: "Last resort" is to mark a member `mutable`. Casting away `const` from an object that was *defined* `const` is UB.

Comment: @m.m "If you don't like it, perhaps consider switching to a different language." Don't talk like a zealot, it adds nothing to the debate. Not everything is black and white. The pointer is in fact const, in the sense that it should never ever change. So why do I change it you ask? For *deserialize* process, which is actually a type of constructor that deserialize object from file. C++ is nice, but it got its imperfections and sometimes its OK to search for less orthodox methods.

Comment: @RustyX see my last comment to n.m.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is undefined behavior to modify in any way a variable declared as `const` outside of its construction or destruction.

```
const std::shared_ptr<int> second
```

this is a variable declared as `const`.

There is no standard compliant way to change what it refers to after construction and before destruction.

That being said, manually calling the destructor and constructing a new `shared_ptr` in the same spot might be legal, I am uncertain.  You definitely cannot refer to said `shared_ptr` by its original name, and possibly leaving the scope where the original `shared_ptr` existed is illegal (as the destructor tries to destroy the *original* object, which the compiler can *prove* is an empty shared pointer (or a non-empty one) based on how the `const` object was constructed).

This is a bad idea even if you could make an argument the standard permits it.

`const` objects cannot be changed.

...

Your cast to a `shared_ptr<int>` simply creates a temporary copy.  It is then assigned to, and the temporary copy is changed.  Then the temporary copy is discarded.  The `const shared_ptr<int>` not being modified is expected behavior.  The legality of assigning to a temporary copy is because `shared_ptr` and most of the `std` library was designed before we had the ability to overload `operator=` based on the r/lvalue-ness of the left hand side.

...

Now, why is this the case?  Actual `const`ness is used by the compiler as an optimization hint.

```
{
  const std::shared_ptr<int> bob = std::make_shared<int>();
}
```

in the above case, the compiler can know *for certain* that `bob` is non-empty at the end of the scope.  Nothing can be done to `bob` that could make it empty and still leave you with defined behavior.

So the compiler can eliminate the branch at the end of the scope when destroying `bob` that checks if the pointer is null.

Similar optimizations could occur if you pass `bob` to an `inline` function that checks for `bob`'s null state; the compiler can omit the check.

Suppose you pass bob to

```
void secret_code( std::shared_ptr<int> const& );
```

where the compiler cannot see into the implementation of `secret_code`.  It can assume that *secret code will not edit bob*.

If it wasn't declared `const`, `secret_code` could legally do a `const_cast<std::shared_ptr&>` on the parameter and set it to null; but if the argument to `secret_code` is *actually `const`* this is undefined behavior.  (Any code casting away const is responsible for guaranteeing that no actual modification of an actual `const` value occurs by doing so)

Without `const` on `bob`, the compiler could not guarantee:

```
{
  const std::shared_ptr<int> bob = std::make_shared<int>();
  secret_code(bob);
  if (bob) {
    std::cout << "guaranteed to run"
  }
}
```

that the `guaranteed to run` string would be printed.

With `const` on `bob`, the compiler is free to elimiate the `if` check above.

...

Now, do not confuse my explanation asto *why* the standard states you cannot edit `const` stack variables with "if this doesn't happen there is no problem".  The standard states you shall not do it; the consequences if you do it are unbounded and can grow with new versions of your compiler.

...

From comments:

> For deserialize process, which is actually a type of constructor that deserialize object from file. C++ is nice, but it got its imperfections and sometimes its OK to search for less orthodox methods.

If it is a *constructor*, make it a *constructor*.

In C++17 a function returning a `T` has basically equal standing to a real constructor in many ways (due to guaranteed elision).  In C++14, this isn't quite true (you also need a move constructor, and the compiler needs to elide it).

So a deserialization constructor for a type `T` in C++ needs to return a `T`, it cannot take a `T` by-reference and be a real constructor.

Composing this is a bit of a pain, but it can be done.  Using the same code for serialization and deserialization is even more of a pain (I cannot off hand figure out how).